# lvalue reference on rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, rvalue, lvalue

I have an interesting example to understand lvalue reference, rvalue reference, and std::forward. Maybe it will be a useful example for a deep understating concept.

```
void foo(int&& a){
  cout<<"foo&&"<<endl;
}

void foo(int& a){
  cout<<"foo&"<<endl;
}

template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& a){
  cout<<"wrapperTemplate"<<endl;
  foo(forward<T>(a));
};

int main()
{
  double&& a=5;
  double& t=a;
  wrapper(t);
}
```

The output is:

```
wrapperTemplate
foo&&
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or did you just want to share the example?

Comment: Please read [ask] and clearly state your question.  You are allowed to ask and answer your own question if you think it's appropriate and you have done the necessary search for duplicates.

Comment: `std::forward` has no bearing on the output in this program.  Your `double` is being implicitly converted to a temporary `int`.  That's why the `int` is an r-value.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site. While you are welcome to share knowledge, it must be presented in a question+answer format. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the lvalue reference version, as `t` is a `double` and `foo()` expects an `int`. And you can't bind the temporary generated by the implict cast from `double` to `int` to an lvalue reference. The temporary is an rvalue, so can be used to call the rvalue overload.

The fact that `a` is an rvalue reference doesn't change the result:

```cpp
double a=5;
double& t=a;
wrapper(t);
```

still prints:

```
wrapperTemplate
foo&&
```

https://godbolt.org/z/89T7Wzc8e

If the types do match, the lvalue reference function is called:

```cpp
int a=5;
int& t=a;
wrapper(t);
```

prints:

```
wrapperTemplate
foo&
```

https://godbolt.org/z/chnzaKhGf

If you use `std::move()`, you get back to the rvalue reference version:

```cpp
int a=5;
int& t=a;
wrapper(std::move(t));
```

prints:

```
wrapperTemplate
foo&&
```

https://godbolt.org/z/68KPYrhYP

Removing `wrapper` also doesn't change the behaviour:

```cpp
double a=5;
foo(a);
int b=5;
foo(b);
foo(std::move(b));
```

prints:

```
foo&&
foo&
foo&&
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fds6sKvhW